# forwarding to another route handler without redirecting in express

Tags: node.js, express

I have the following code :

```
app.get('/payment', function(req, res) {
  // do lots of stuff
});
```

now I want to add the following :

```
app.post('/payment', function(req, res) {
  req.myvar = 'put something here';
  // now do the same as app.get() above
});
```

Obviously I want to reuse the code. I tried doing `next('/payment')` inside the post handler and put it above the get handler, but no luck, probably because they are different VERBs.

What are my options ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just lift out the middleware to its own function and use it in both routes.

```
function doLotsOfStuff (req, res) {
  // do lots of stuff
}

app.get('/payment', doLotsOfStuff);

app.post('/payment', function(req, res, next) {
  req.myvar = 'put something here';
  next();
}, doLotsOfStuff);
```

Comment: cool, what's the last argument to app.post do ? that is probably the stuff that I missed

Comment: You mean `.next()`? That's yielding to the next middleware. Or `doLotsOfStuff`? That's so that the next middleware is the same as for the GET verb.

Comment: nice. didn't know you could chain more middlewares